# Notepad++ regular expression, get the first digit of a number

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a text in notepad++ (addresses) that is stored in the following form :
Some numbers (1 or more) than some text then some number then some text
i want to search and replace all this with :
The first numbers then the text then the sentence "Postal Code" then the numbers than the rest of the text
Example :

> 15 queen street 47000 Amsterdam

Becomes :

> 15 queen street Postal Code 47000 Amsterdam

I have tried this code :
`^(\d*)(.*)(\d)`
replaced with :
`\1\2 Postal Code \3`
It doesn't work.. I have tried so many other codes in my head but non is working
Because notepad gets the whole second numbers.. If it could take just the first digit of the second numbers the problem would be solved

Comment: Answers are already correct but if you wanted you could simplify this to replace `^(\d*\D*)` with `\1Postal Code `

Answer (score 4):

You need to add `?` for a non greedy match and it would match the first digit of the last group. I would also change and use the `+` quantifier instead since you state it begins with some numbers (`1` or more).

How about the following?

```
Find: ^(\d+)(.*?)(\d)
Replace: \1\2Postal Code \3
```

You could simplify this a bit if you wanted to.

```
Find: ^(\d+\D+)(?=\d)
Replace: \1Postal Code
```

Given your input, with both the above expressions I get the following output:

```
15 queen street Postal Code 47000 Amsterdam
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `.*?` for the reluctant (non-greedy) quantifier.

docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/quant.html